# Many mapfiles with few layers, or all layers in one mapfile?

Tags: mapserver, mapfile

I am using MapServer 6 and defining maps with [mapfiles](http://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/).

I have a page where 20 map compositions (~20*5=~100 layers) are possible by varing LAYER/DATA  field and some classes of layers... So I can express each map  by a mapfile (20 mapfiles) or I can put all layers in the same mapfile... This is the question,

**What is better (have better performance), many mapfiles with few layers each, or one  mapfile with all (many) layers?**

---

If the answer need some context... I am accessing Mapserver by this URL, where layer names (L1**a**,L2**b**) and mapfile name (MF**c**.map) can vary,

example/cgi-bin/mapserv?LAYERS=L1a,L2b,L3,L4,L5,L6&MAP=MFc.map&FORMAT=image%2Fjpeg&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&STYLES=&SRS=epsg:29183&WIDTH=612&HEIGHT=516&BBOX=....

The combinatory is:

1. *Many mapfiles* (c=1..20, a=1, b=1..5): a templating software generated 20 mapfiles, each with ~5 layers.
2. *One mapfile* (c=1, a=1..20, b=1..5): a templating software can generate a mafile with all ~200 layers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best by far is to use one main mapfile with INCLUDE directives to call other mapfiles (all of them being "simple and specific Map Files" btw). This will definitely speed things up. I tested that and the result is quite impressive. This idea comes from here: http://mapserver.org/es/optimization/mapfile.html

"If you have a complex application, consider using multiple simple and specific Map Files in place of one large ‘do everything’ Map File."

Check this very nice post and blog from Simon, he's a very nice guy working with mapserver and related things: http://smercier1.mapgears.com/blog/?p=37. I used these performance tips and they do work. Here you have another [link](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2008/10/mapserverpostgis-performance-tips.html), but Simon basically explained already that in his blog.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Hum... To use the [INCLUDE](http://mapserver.org/mapfile/include.html) directive for including 20 mapfile files, why (??). PS:  Simon say nothing about INCLUDE.

Comment: because it works, at least for me, I edited my answer. I never said that Simon explained that.

Comment: Ok (thanks!), now it makes sense, with your edit and our discussion; but try to be objective for other readers: "the best (...) is to use one main mapfile" is a contradiction with "consider using multiple simple and specific Map Files".

Comment: (you're welcome) I think you misunderstood that part, one main map file means that other mapfiles will be called from this main map file. Thus this is done to split your one, big, do-everything map file. This means what you quoted recently: consider using multiple simple and specific Map Files", I don't see the contradiction here.

Comment: The title of the question "show directions" to the reader: "many tiny mapfile VS one big mapfiles", so answer is "many" or is "one".  Another subject: your [mapserver/mapfile link](http://mapserver.org/es/optimization/mapfile.html#index-2) have another issue (!), "*Turn off unnecessary layers; the more layers MapServer is displaying, the more time it takes* (...) *is particularly true of remote WMS*".

Answer (score -1):

(this answer is a copy) "Translating" the @Gery answer to "my question language": **use many mapfiles**.

As Gary showed, the [mapfile guide](http://mapserver.org/es/optimization/mapfile.html#index-2) have the answer:

> If you have a complex application, consider using multiple simple and
>   specific Map Files in place of one large ‘do everything’ MapFile.

Particularly for remote WMS, as in the question context, another peformance tip, that will speed things up, is to simplify: if there are many layers, *"(...) turn off unnecessary layers; the more layers MapServer is displaying, the more time it takes. (...)"* (same link).

---

Do you (reader) have some benchmarking comparing big and tiny mapfiles?